# How do you do this transformation of two Euler's number formula?

Tags: eulers-number-e

I found a simple programming problem that asks how to get Euler's number by iteration. I do not talk about this problem here,
but when I researched the definition of Euler's number (well, I think I am already learned them), I found two formulas.

One has the definition of limit, and another is defined by partial sum.
So, I raise the question. How can these different formulas transform into each other? Is it even possible?

If it's possible,

How to prove/transform left to right?

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}(1+{1\over{n}})^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty {1 \over n!} $$

###### off-topic note

I think I could solve the problem by using partial sum definition.
the program like this

```
double a[2]={1,1}
for(int i=1;i>1;i++){
   a[0]*= 1.0/i
   a[1]+= a[0]
   if (a[0]<pow(0.1,15){break;}
}
printf("e=%f",a[1])
```

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Yes, Thank you so much! I couldn't figure out how to search for this problem.

Comment: @Shaun Sorry, I will edit this now

Comment: Also see [Tannery's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tannery%27s_theorem) on Wikipedia.

Comment: @bjorn93 I am happy to know this theorem! Thank you!

Comment: Also, it is $1+1/n$, not $1+1/n!$.

Comment: @marty cohen Oh, yes, I have corrected it! Thank you so much!!